# How do I cast a u64 value to a generic numeric type?

Tags: rust

I would like to cast a u64 value to a generic numeric type, something like

```
fn f<T: AppropriateTrait>(v: u64) -> T {
    v as T
}
```

and have it behave semantically like, e.g., `259u64 as u8`, i.e., it should just take the least significant bits. Unfortunately, the `FromPrimitive::from_u64` function returns an `Option<T>`, with `None` if the input value doesn't fit.

This here works:

```
fn f<T: FromPrimitive + Int + ToPrimitive>(v: u64) -> T {
    T::from_u64(v & T::max_value().to_u64().unwrap()).unwrap()
}
```

But it's very verbose and inelegant. Is there a better way?

*Edit*: I'm only interested in casting to integer types like u8, u16, etc., no funky stuff.

Comment: Why do you want it as a separate function? `v as u8` does what you desire just fine, and if you need it as a function then `|v| v as u8` will work fine.

Comment: @Chris: The function above is of course only the essence of what I want to do – or should I have posted 2000+ lines of code? I cannot write `v as u8` because `u8` was just an example. Trust me, I need a cast to a generic type, not to a specific type.

Comment: With the request given, it’s tricky to perceive the *purpose* of the whole question, why the function can be needed. Something a little more would probably be helpful.

Comment: The exact context of my problem would go beyond the scope of the question and isn't really needed for a solution. But if you're interested: I develop software for formal verification and want to simulate boolean functions using lookup-tables. For this, I have a template of 6 u64 values which have to be truncated to the length needed for the respective number of boolean inputs (e.g., u16 for 4 inputs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this particularly efficiently is to define your own trait with the desired effect; especially if you are getting to something more complex, this will often be what you desire (though definitely not always). For this case, you might go for something like this:

```rust
trait FromU64 {
    fn from_u64(v: u64) -> Self;
}

macro_rules! impl_from_u64 {
    ($($ty:ty)*) => {
        $(
            impl FromU64 for $ty {
                #[inline]
                fn from_u64(v: u64) -> $ty {
                    v as $ty
                }
            }
        )*
    }
}

impl_from_u64!(u8 u16 u32 u64 usize);
```

Your original `f::<T>` would then be `<T as FromU64>::from_u64`, or alternatively

```rust
fn f<T: FromU64>(v: u64) -> T {
    FromU64::from_u64(T)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a very idomatic solution!